# Communicating between IFRAME and an entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I couldn't make a request to a remote server using JavaScript in the `onload` function due to *access is denied* insanity. So, just to make CRM obey, I set up an *IFRAME* and connect that to a HTML page running my JavaScript. Now, provided that I get some values inside the script (run in an *IFRAME*) how can I communicate them to a method in the holding parent?

Not quite sure how to explain it more detailed so please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had the joy of connecting to a web service and retrieve some data. When that’s been achieved, I found myself sitting on the said data not exactly knowing where to put it.

To make the long story short, I used the following source code.

```javascript
parent.window.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes
  .get("new_Konrad").setValue("Viltersten");
```

Notable is the fact that in order to communicate with the parent form, the HTML file (where my JavaScript resided), needed to be placed as a web resource within the CRM structure. By other words, just by pointing to an external “*http://some.where/some.thing*” we can consume a service but won’t be able to convey the obtained information up the CRM server, at least not when developing a solution for the on-line version.

Answer (score 2):

The access is denied is the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You're going to run into the same problem from the IFRAME unless you're serving the page or just the script src from the same server you're subsequently trying to make the AJAX request to.

Assuming you are doing the latter then you just need to make sure you have unchecked the "Restrict cross-frame scripting" option on the IFRAME you added to the CRM form.  From the IFRAME you will now have access to your function that you've defined at global scope on the parent CRM form via `window.parent.yourfunctionNameHere(xyz)`.

Answer (score 2):

postMessage sounds like it might fit.

`window.postMessage`, when called, causes a MessageEvent to be dispatched at the target window when any pending script that must be executed completes (e.g. remaining event handlers if window.postMessage is called from an event handler, previously-set pending timeouts, etc.). The MessageEvent has the type message, a data property which is set to the string value of the first argument provided to window.postMessage, an origin property corresponding to the origin of the main document in the window calling window.postMessage at the time window.postMessage was called, and a source property which is the window from which window.postMessage is called.

To use window.postMessage, an event listener must be attached:

```javascript
// Internet Explorer
window.attachEvent('onmessage',receiveMessage);

// Opera/Mozilla/Webkit
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

And a `receiveMessage` function must be declared:

```javascript
function receiveMessage(event) {
    // do something with event.data;
}
```

The off-site iframe must also send events properly via postMessage:

```javascript
<script>window.parent.postMessage('foo','*')</script>
```

Any window may access this method on any other window, at any time, regardless of the location of the document in the window, to send it a message. Consequently, any event listener used to receive messages must first check the identity of the sender of the message, using the origin and possibly source properties. This cannot be understated: Failure to check the origin and possibly source properties enables cross-site scripting attacks.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage