# Account Number vs Accountid - iFrames in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm-2011

With iFrames I currently know how to include them on an Account in CRM using getId() function. I have a need to be able to do this by accountnumber instead. Is there a function or solution out there to accomplish this?

Thanks for all the help!

-Sam

EDIT: After taking glosrob's advice I added the get('accountnumber') row which got me closer to where I want to be but it is not producing correct results. Here is the code I'm using to produce the IFRAME:

```
function SetReport() {
    var id = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('accountnumber')
    var serverAndOrgUrl = '(*Company URL*)&AccountNumber=';
    var mycmd = '&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false'
    var iframeSrc = serverAndOrgUrl + id + mycmd;

    var report = document.createElement("iframe");
    report.setAttribute('id', 'reportFrame');
    report.setAttribute('name', 'reportFrame');
    report.setAttribute('src', iframeSrc);
    report.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    report.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    report.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
    report.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');

    var reportDiv = document.createElement("div");
    reportDiv.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    reportDiv.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    reportDiv.appendChild(report);
    document.body.appendChild(reportDiv);

    function ShowFrame() {
        if(report.readyState == "complete") {
            menubar = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('mnuBar1');
            if(menubar != null) {
                menubar.style.display = "none";
            }

            editFilter = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('trEditFilter');
            if(editFilter != null) {
                editFilter.style.display = "none";              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The IFRAME is produced but no data shows up on Accounts where there should be data. It makes me think that the account numbers aren't matching properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

-Sam

Comment: Out of interest, if you alert the value of id, what result do you see? e.g. add alert(id); after the first line?

Comment: Don't bump, it is bad etiquette. There is a question there for you to answer.

Comment: Hi glosrob, I'm sorry about that bump, won't happen again. I actually did not see the comment you posted when I checked the post today. I put that alert in there and it came back with 'undefined' - I received another helpful hint about this issue but have not been able to piece it together yet. 

Here's the note a former colleague sent me: "For the account number, you would take the value from the field on the form. Also, hide the iframe on a create form because no account number exists"

I somewhat understand what he is saying but get confused at the 'create form' piece.. 

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach here [Communicating between IFRAME and an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571127/communicating-between-iframe-and-an-entity)

Essentially you can access the parent form's `Xrm` object which means you can access the `accountnumber` property with something like:

```
parent.window.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('accountnumber')
```

Edit: just seen your comment...

> I put that alert in there and it came back with 'undefined'. For the account number, you would take the value from the field on the form.

Those two would be related. You would need to have the `accountnumber` on the form, even if it is hidden.

You may also need to uncheck 'Restrict Cross Site Scripting' on the form properties.

> Also, hide the iframe on a create form because no account number exists

Well yes, if the account has not been created then obviously there is no related data there to retrieve and so doing so will be a waste of time - not sure I have much more to add to that?

To test if a form is in create mode, you can use

```
Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1//CREATE MODE
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_getFormType)

You could test for create mode and then show/hide the section depending on whether it is in create mode or not.

Comment: That gets me further than I was but for some reason it does not match the accountnumber properly. It always returns me with no data(even on the accounts where I know data should populate). Here is my code for anyone that can help. I am hiding the URL - it will be notated as (*URL*)

Comment: Sorry about the jumbled code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted the jumbled code and moved it into an edit on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The following line in you question is getting the accountnumber attribute object:

```
var id = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('accountnumber')
```

This needs to be updated in order to get the value of the accountnumber so that you can use it in your report URL:

```
var id = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('accountnumber').getValue()
```